# Confusing error when splitting a string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, split

I have this line of code:

`string[] ids = Request.Params["service"].Split(",");`

the values in `Request.Params["service"]` are: `"1,2"`

Why am I getting:

```
Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments
Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char[]'
```

This makes no sense to me....

The error happens on everything to the right of the equal sign

Comment: split takes an array of chars or a single char not  string as its paramter

Comment: the split expect a char so ',' instead of ","

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to pass a character (`System.Char`), not a `string`:

```
string[] ids = Request.Params["service"].Split(',');
```

There is no overload to [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7h14879.aspx) that takes a `params string[]` or a single `string`, which is what would be required to make your code work.

If you wanted to split with a string (or multiple strings), you would need to use a `string[]` and specify splitting options:

```
string[] ids = Request.Params["service"].Split(new[]{","}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: There is one to a string[], but as he's only using a character anyways it doesn't matter. +1.

Comment: @ofstream That's why I mentioned explicitly `params string[]`, not `string[]` - though the `string[]` also *requires* `StringSplitOptions` in addition to the array.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the overload with the [`params Char[]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx):

```
string[] ids = Request.Params["service"].Split(',');
```

Answer (score 2):

As others said on here your provided (",") the double quote denotes a string and the Split function accepts a Character array or char[]. Use (',') , the single quote denotes a character.  You can also pass along StringSplitOptions which if you happen to get empty values in your string[] it requires a char[] to be passed along with it, illustrated below.

```
        string splitMe = "test1,test2,";
        string[] splitted1 = splitMe.Split(',');
        string[] splitted2 = splitMe.Split(new char[]{','},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        //Will be length 3 due to extra comma
        MessageBox.Show(splitted1.Length.ToString());
        //Will be length 2, Removed the empty entry since there was nothing after the comma
        MessageBox.Show(splitted2.Length.ToString());
```

Answer (score -1):

In the line
`Request.Params["service"].Split(",");`

You're splitting by `","` instead of `','`

The `.Split()` method takes an array of characters, not a string